# How to Position jPlayer

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jplayer

I can't seem to figure out how to position jPlayer.

I looked at jPlayer's documentation which says that jPlayer is set to be absolute positioned by default, but it doesn't appear to be because it seems to be part of the flow of the page, not out of the flow like an absolutely positioned element is.

Also, I tried applying the left, top, bottom, and right CSS properties to a bunch of elements that the jPlayer is made of and not a single attempt made any change.

Also, adding options into the javascript section on jPlayer don't seem to do anything either. I'm talking about the options listed here: http://www.jplayer.org/0.2.2/developer-guide/. I tried top and left and they did nothing.

Comment: do you have a development page you could link to? That would make it easier to suggest a relevant fix. You can position jPlayer any way you like with CSS. And is there any reason you linked to an ancient version of the Documentation, above?

Comment: Because was the only thing I could find on the subject with a google search. I'll see what I can do. Also you said it can be done with CSS, but you didn't say which element it is that you have to position with CSS

Answer (score 1):

Put this in the main `div` or first `div` tag. Then, once you are done with it, you can edit the position as you wish:

```
style="position: absolute;left: 100px;top: 40px;"
```

Answer (score 0):

You have full control of the HTML Markup and CSS look/feel of your jPlayer instance. Example below ([see Fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/75lb/T82sX/))

With this standard GUI markup (taken from the jPlayer demos)

```
<div id="player"></div>
<div id="jp_container_1" class="jp-audio">
    <div class="jp-type-single">
        <div class="jp-gui jp-interface">
            <ul class="jp-controls">
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-play" tabindex="1">play</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-pause" tabindex="1" style="display: none; ">pause</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-stop" tabindex="1">stop</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-mute" tabindex="1" title="mute">mute</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-unmute" tabindex="1" title="unmute" style="display: none; ">unmute</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-volume-max" tabindex="1" title="max volume">max volume</a></li>
            </ul>
            <div class="jp-progress">
                <div class="jp-seek-bar">
                    <div class="jp-play-bar"></div>

                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-volume-bar">
                <div class="jp-volume-bar-value"></div>
            </div>
            <div class="jp-current-time"></div>
            <div class="jp-duration"></div>
            <ul class="jp-toggles">
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat" tabindex="1" title="repeat">repeat</a></li>
                <li><a href="javascript:;" class="jp-repeat-off" tabindex="1" title="repeat off" style="display: none; ">repeat off</a></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-title">
            <ul>
                <li></li>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="jp-no-solution" style="display: none; ">
            <span>Update Required</span>
            To play the media you will need to either update your browser to a recent version or update your <a href="http://get.adobe.com/flashplayer/" target="_blank">Flash plugin</a>.
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

you can instantiate a player with this javascript

```
$(function() {
    $("#player").jPlayer({
        swfPath: "http://www.jplayer.org/latest/js/Jplayer.swf",
        supplied: "mp3",
        ready: function() {
            $(this).jPlayer("setMedia", {
                mp3:"http://static1.grsites.com/archive/sounds/animals/animals001.mp3"
            });
        }
    });         
});
```

this renders plain, unstyled HTML in your browser. You can style your jPlayer GUI as you please. For example, by adding some positioning rules

```
.jp-play, .jp-pause {
    position:absolute;
    left: 7em;
    top: 3em
}
```